# Error in installation of rmagick [in rails 2.3.5]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, rmagick

I was trying to install rmagick gem in rails 2.3.5 . but I could not install as it shows error. Same error comes in both rvm and system.

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
>       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
>   extconf.rb:153: undefined (?...) sequence: /^Version: ImageMagick\s+(?\d+.\d+.\d+-\d+)\s+(?\S+)\s+(?\S+)\s+(?\S+)/
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.4 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.4/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

this was the error.

Already Installed imagemagick,libmagickwand-dev, libxml2-dev, libxslt-dev,libgraphics-magick-perl, libgraphicsmagick++1-dev, libgraphicsmagick++3, libgraphicsmagick1-dev, libgraphicsmagick3 (tried everything got from google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the very latest version, you could try:

```
gem install rmagick -v 2.13.3
```

And see if the previous one works for you.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like v2.13.4 needs some extra stuff installed, simply not only install libs but also:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

This fixed it for me.

FYI, I got the following error:

```
checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```